# Linking Different types of information using trie data structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, trie

So I want to create a record for a phone directory that stores **(ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME)** using **tries data structure**.

but I'm super confused! how can I link the trie of IDs with the trie of FIRST_NAMEs and LAST_NAMEs trie
in a way that enable me to search for a username by ID of the phone.

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Simply store the information in a heap-allocated object. Store a pointer to it in your various tries.

Given

```
struct User {
    std::string id, first_name, last_name;
};
```

You would insert a new user like so:

```
User * bart = new User{"123", "Bart", "Simpson"};
id_trie.insert(bart->id, bart);
fn_trie.insert(bart->first_name, bart);
ln_trie.insert(bart->last_name, bart);
```

Where the three trie datastructures could use a node that looks like the following:

```
struct trie_node {
    User * user;
    std::map<char, trie_node *> children;
};
```

where `user` is either a `nullptr` or a pointer to a `User`.

Exercise: adapt this to allow multiple users (eg if they share the same first or last name)